# Add image and checkbox in select tag

Tags: angularjs

How to add image and check box in `<option>` tag in angular js.

I have already done so much google but nothing will help.
I also installed 'ui-select' plugin but that will not work for me

Thanks.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/f80OwHRTKueyrbKRoV7H?p=preview

Comment: I already tried this not work for me

Comment: please add what you have tried!!

Comment: I add that I have tried 'ui-select', and in this plunker link that is used.